# A question on the Hilbert-Kamke problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations

The Hilbert-Kamke problem consists in studying the integral solutions of the Diophantine system
$$
x_1^i + \dots + x_s^i = n_i \text{ for } 1\leq i\leq k
$$
with $x_i\geq 0$ for $i = 1,\dots,k$.

I am interested in the case $k = 2$:
$$
S_2 = \left\lbrace\begin{array}{lll}
x_1 + \dots + x_s & = & n_1;\\ 
x_1^2 + \dots + x_s^2 & = & n_2;
\end{array}\right.
$$
with $x_i\geq 0$ for $i = 1,\dots,k$. In my case $n_1,n_2,s$ are polynomials depending on a varibale $r$. I would like to ask whether there exists an asymptotic formula for the number of solutions of $S_2$